# AWS Your account is not ready for posting messages yet

Tags: amazon-web-services

I just signed up to the forum for AWS using my console account. All good.

I go post for the first time and I get:

`Your account is not ready for posting messages yet`

I do not have an ad blocker so I have not found any other solutions to this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Give it a few hours... that issue should remedy itself.

Comment: @Michael Thanks! A few hours to be able to post help question even by logging in with a paying customer account? So much for the industry leading cloud provider!

Comment: I'm only going off of anecdotal evidence that sometime this apparently does happen on new accounts... there is some kind of delay that people occasionally report. I've never had the issue, myself.  If you are feeling impatient, and you don't have a paid technical support plan, you could try opening a *billing* support request with AWS support.  Or post your issue here or at http://serverfault.com as appropriate.

Comment: This is a ridiculous regulation. I have search hours on the internet trying to solve a problem I encountered with their Route53 service. None of the existing posts answers my problem. Now I have to wait a few more hours to post my question?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If this is a persistent problem, the solution is to open a ticket with support.

According to [this document](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/error-forum-post/), this is to help reduce the amount of spam.  New accounts accumulate the ability to post messages over time.

Answer (score 3):

To limit spam posted to the AWS forums, the number of messages an account can post is limited. The number of messages an account can post steadily increases over time. Newly activated accounts might not be able to post any messages for a few hours.
[Look here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/error-forum-post/) for more info. 
I could posted my question in forum with in 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

Just wait for a while, approximately 30 mins. It's automatically solved.