# Logged into AWS forums but creating new thread prompts forum signup?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am logged into the AWS forums and have previously created an AWS Nickname posting which I used to create a post before.

Currently, the AWS forums show me as logged in, but when I try and create a new thread it says I need to pick an "AWS Nickname" and "Forum Email". If I try and put my Nickname I created before it says that Nickname is already in use, and if I try and use my email, it says that email is already registered.

How is it possible for the forums to recognize my nickname?

I have tried logging in and logging out with no success.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an issue with the Amazon forums, not a programming question.

Comment: How do you know that you are logged into the AWS forums?

Comment: At the top right it shows the option to 'logout'. Thought it was fine to ask here based off this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931355/aws-your-account-is-not-ready-for-posting-messages-yet

Comment: This question should definitely NOT be closed.  I ran into this today and this is the only solution I found.  Closing important questions and solutions is a sure way to ruin Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this exact issue. This is what I did

1. Login to the AWS Management console. Make sure to switch to your main account (This didn't work for me while I was assuming a "role").
2. On the upper right click `Support > Forums`
3. You should automatically be logged into the forums & post as usual

You'll know it works if the welcome header looks like:

```
Welcome, <username> | Logout | Your Stuff | Private Messages () | Forums Help
```

When I was experiencing the error, the welcome header looked like this:

```
Welcome | Logout | Forums Help
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Does this work with IAM users at all? I'm signed in as an IAM user, not assuming role, and it gives me the (dodgy) welcome header you mention and HTTP 500 every time I post. Tried it on 3 browsers across 2 devices... :S

Comment: Ok, solved it. You have to log out of AWS in other tabs (or delete cookies) and then click the Login link in AWS Forums to be presented with the Nickname/email prompt. From then on it works.